# Datatables and YADCF - multi-select filter

Tags: datatables, multi-select, yadcf

Two problems.

First, if I enable **scrollX** on my datatable then the **multi-select** filter drop-down box is obscured by the rest of the table (zindex problem?).

Second, the **muti-select** filter drop-down box seems to populate with any initial content of the datatable when I call yadcf.init, but the multi-select-box values do not update when the content of the datatable changes.  Other filters work fine this way.

```
   yadcf.init(dtObject, [{
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "multi_select",
        select_type: 'chosen'
    }], 'header');
```

Comment: please provide a test page with the issue, also try `multi_select` without `        select_type: 'chosen'` to see where is the problem

Comment: If I remove the select_type: 'chosen' option the filter drop-down-list gets updated when I add new data to the table.

Comment: … and the table header expands to fit the number of options in the list (thought it is no longer a drop-down-list).

Comment: I updated to the yadcf 0.9.3 and the filter's drop-down-list is now being refreshed properly when new data is added to the datatable.  So the only problem remaining is the obscured drop-down-list when scrollx is enabled.

Comment: Example page added at https://jsfiddle.net/fpho7reu/30/

Comment: I don't think that chosen filter will be able to use along with `scrollX` (at least not in the near future) Its being hidden because of the way DT display its header/chosen shows its elements,  you can try using select2 instead of chosen and in case of other issues open it on github

Comment: Unfortunately, select2 seems to suffer the exact same problem.  See https://jsfiddle.net/kentvickery/fpho7reu/39/ for an example using the select2 filter.